# scripting bridge header files

Tags: cocoa, scripting-bridge

how can I generate scripting bridge files at runtime? I want to use scripting bridge to quit an appliction, but that application is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

[From the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-DontLinkElementID_12):

> To create a header file, you need to run two command-line tools—sdef and sdp—together, with the output from one piped to the other. This is the recommended syntax:
>
> `sdef /path/to/application.app | sdp -fh --basename applicationName`

Comment: I've have a similar question... specifically, running on Lion, do I need to install sdef and sep?  It doesn't appear that I have these command line utilities on my machine, because I get a -bash command not found error foe each when trying to use the above command...

Comment: @GregSteiner they should be installed on every Mac.

Comment: if that's the case, why do you think I might be getting the -bash errors?

Comment: @GregSteiner no idea; sounds like it'd be a great question on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Scripting Bridge is a compile-time technology. You may be able to generate the header at run-time, but what good would that do to your compiled application?

Try with AppleScript:

```
NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"tell application \"%@\" to quit", appName];
NSAppleScript* as = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: script] autorelease];
[as executeAndReturnError: nil];
```

Given an app name `appName`, you should be able to send it a `quit` event quickly and easily.